# In Angular 8 how to make mat-drawer resizable by dragging the edge of the drawer?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to figure out how to make [mat-drawer / side-nav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) resizable by dragging the right edge of the drawer when it is open.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-resizable-columns?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresizable%2Fresizable.directive.ts)  is a nice example of making table columns resizable. Would someone suggest how this could be applied to the mat-drawer / side-nav?

I tried different ways to massage the code of the table example, but no success.

E.g: I tried changing in : \resizable.component.ts:

```
selector: "th[resizable]",
```

to:

```
 selector: "mat-drawer[resizable]",
```

and than apply:

```
 <mat-drawer resizable #drawer mode="side">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to put together a fairly nice and simple solution thanks to [mattlewis92](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-resizable-element) like this:

1. Download and install a small dependency:
   [angular-resizable-element](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element)

   - make sure you import/export the dependency module:
     ***ResizableModule***
     in the root or an exported module
2. In your xxx.component.html (HTML template/view) file

   ```
   < mat-drawer-container autosize >

     <mat-drawer #drawer 
                 mode="side"
                 [(opened)]="isOpen_YourVariable"

                 mwlResizable
                 [enableGhostResize]="true"
                 [ngStyle]="resizeStyle"
                 [validateResize]="resizeValidate"
                 [resizeEdges]="{right: true}"
                 (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)" >

      Place here the show/hide content e.g. vertical menu.

    </mat-drawer>

    <mat-drawer-content>
      Place here the visible content - right located from the show/hide drawer
    </mat-drawer-content>

   </mat-drawer-container>
   ```
3. In your xxx.component.ts file

   ```
   import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';

   @Component({
     selector: 'xxx',
     templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.scss']
   })
   export class XXXComponent {

     resizeStyle: object = {};

     isOpen_YourVariable = true;

                      /**
                       * Set initial max. width of the drawer
                       */

    ngOnInit() {
        this.resizeStyle = {
          "max-width": `30%`,
        };
    }

                      /**
                       * Validates resize positions
                       * (used for drawer/sidenav width)
                       * @param event 
                       */
    resizeValidate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
      const MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX: number = 50;
      if (
        event.rectangle.width &&
        event.rectangle.height &&
        (event.rectangle.width < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX ||
          event.rectangle.height < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX)
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

                      /**
                       * Finilizes resize positions
                       * (used for drawer/sidenav width)
                       * @param event 
                       */
    onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
      this.resizeStyle = {
                       // enable/disable these per your needs
        //position: 'fixed',
        //left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
        //top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
        //height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`,
        width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
      };
    }
   }
   ```

And that should do. Enjoy.

Comment: Sadly,, this alone does not work very well. The resize handle seems to be only 1pix wide so it is difficult to select. The mat-drawer-content is not resized until you close and reopen the drawer which is not good UX. In addition some content overflows outside of the drawer while you are dragging, though it fixes itself when you stop... not sure what is going on there since it even does it when CSS overflow is hidden on the drawer.

This is a good starting point though.